# How can I ask for remaining session lifespan without extending it?

Tags: session, jsf

I want to display an accurate timer showing the remaining session lifetime on the client side. Until now I've used a client side JavaScript timer which is not as accurate as I want it to be. Beside that it doesn't reflect any session touches via AJAX which reset the timeout on server side.

But if I use something like this the session timeout is refreshed upon every update. So the session actually never times out. How can I avoid this?

```
<a4j:poll enabled="true" interval="60000" execute="@this" render="@form" />
<h:outputText value="#{sessionLogger.remaining} left @ #{sessionLogger.node}" />
```

Is there any way to retrieve that data without extending the session?

Comment: `SessionLogger` is a small CDI bean in use... I'd gladly use another approach that solves my little problem.