# Is there a way to keep a @WebServlet detached from current session?

Tags: ajax, servlets, jakarta-ee, cookies

I'm using a `@WebServlet` to handle some basic AJAX requests returning JSON to the client. The servlet works as needed... but every request automatically extends the session because the sessionID is part of the cookie sent with the request.

**Is there a way to avoid this?**

There are some requests which I don't want to extend the session. But I don't want to start manipulating the cookie for those. I'm also not easily able to use a second domain for that request (which could avoid the cookie).

Comment: This is slightly related to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35310900/173689

Comment: Your expectation is...a tad unrealistic: you don't want to use a client-side only solution; you don't want to use a server-side solution; you don't want to manipulate the request to disconnect it from the session id?

Comment: I hoped for some server side code like an annotation that marks a @WebServlet detached or similar. Also cookie manipulation on the client side is rather unstable as the webapp might as well send a session related ajax request at the same time. So I'm looking for some fresh ideas..

Comment: Well there are other communication pipes- Websockets and SSE- that you could explore using, in parallel to HTTP, without necessarily having to rely on the underlying session